# Why is MinGW not recognizing my object files when compiling?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, fortran, mingw, gfortran

I'm using mingw on 64-bit Windows, trying to compile a fortran program. When linking to a library, it returns an error:

`E:/Users/Malcolm/netcdf-4.1.3-antho/lib\libnetcdf.a: member E:/Users/Malcolm/netcdf-4.1.3-antho/lib\libnetcdf.a(libnetcdf_la-stub.o) in archive is not an object`

When I use `nm` on the archive file, it says that the file formats of the object files are not recognized:

`e:\mingw-w64\mingw32\bin\nm.exe: libnetcdf_la-stub.o: File format not recognized` ... etc for the rest of the object files.

If I use `file` on one of the individual object files after extracting it from the archive with 7zip, it returns "ACB archive data".

Below is the compiler-flags section of my Makefile, if it helps:

```
OUTPUTLIB = -LE:/Users/Malcolm/netcdf-4.1.3-antho/lib

OUTPUTOPT = -DNETCDF

LINKOPTS = -lnetcdf -lnetcdff

FC = gfortran

OPTS = -ffree-form -ffree-line-length-none -O3 -finline-functions -fopenmp -fconvert=big-endian

OPTS += -static-libgfortran -static-libgcc

OPTS += -Wl,-Bstatic,--whole-archive -lstdc++ -lpthread -lnetcdf -lnetcdff -lgomp -lquadmath -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--stack,2147483647, --verbose

CPP = cpp -C -P -traditional -Wno-invalid-pp-token -ffreestanding
```

I have not used mingw before this project so it may be that I'm missing something basic.

Comment: Where did `libnetcdf.a` come from?
You should get a version that is built for the same target architecture (win32 or win64), preferably built with the same MinGW compiler.

Comment: I got it from someone else (who did it on win64). I'll ask what compiler they used, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've solved the problem. I was using mingw32, and had also tried it on mingw-w64, not realizing that I installed the i686 version, which is 32-bit.

I installed the x86_64 version of mingw, which is the version used to compile the libraries I was using, and it worked there.